# MS Access Copy Table Structure Only

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I have a number of Linked (ODBC) tables in my MSAccess DB.

I what I want to do is create a copy of each table (preferably the Structure Only).

ive tried,

```
DoCmd.CopyObject , "NewTableName", acTable, "SourceTableName"

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", _
  SrcDatabase, acTable, SrcTable, DstTable, StructureOnly
```

but these just seem to make a copy of the linked table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think ive got it sorted, but ill leave it open incase someone has a better solution,

```
 DoCmd.RunSQL ("Drop Table [LocalTable]")
 DoCmd.RunSQL ("SELECT * INTO [LocalTable] FROM  [ODBCTable];")
```

Comment: A MakeTable query doesn't actually duplicate the source table -- it will not have indexes and the data types can be wildly off. TransferDatabase should allow you to do it and get the full table structure.

Comment: Good enough for ODBC tables: but SELECT INTO doesn't copy indexes. So it's not a great solution for copying MS-Access tables. My advice is: use TransferDatabase with StructureOnly

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Found out that the "DoCmd.Transferdatabase" worked, but had to use "1" instead of the keyword "True". And if the source table is a linked table the destination table appears as linked as well (with the arrow in the table list), although it really is in the local database.